# ASP.NET MVC 3 RemoteAttribute and Separation of concerns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, separation-of-concerns

Isn't it a violation of separation of concerns principle when you use the RemoteAttribute on your model's property to indicate what action and controller to call? It makes you tie your model to a specific controller via string arguments.

Comment: How would you define a remote ajax attribute? How can you not be tied to some action as you need to call it from the client side? The biggest problem with the Remote Attribute (imo) is the fact that there's no real server-side validation (when the model is bound after,say, a form/ajax post).

Comment: ajax request is still a regular http request. You could map it as you map any other request.

Comment: Obviously you could define it as a request. Then you're tied to a specific URL.

Comment: No, you tied it to the controller that will end up handling your request. But you don't specifically tie it to "ValidateMe" action on "Home" controller in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, but so does using all the other DataAnnotations attributes.

Fortunately the model metadata system in MVC is pluggable so you could write your own metadata provider that's not tied to attributes on a model class.

Comment: @marcind... This interests me. Why would you consider DataAnnotations as violating separation of concerns? How I see it DataAnnotations define the rules that your model complies to. I don't see, for example, how Required or Range defy separation of concerns, as they basically act as Metadata for properties. While other classes know how to interpret this metadata into validation/etc this is not a concern that falls upon the class that has the metadata.

Comment: sorry, meant to say that different people approach seperation of concerns differently and there are some who feel that attributes tie the data models too closely with the business rules, etc. It's a matter of personal preference in my opinion. (And technically, a large number of the DataAnnotations attributes are in fact what performs the validation)